# Canvas App - signedRequest is null on postback

Tags: canvas

I developed Canvas web APP using Java and I have a JSP page that renders the page and a FORM that takes input text and submit button .

After I press the Submit ,which in turn call the javascript function on click and do the AJAX post call which is also working fine, but on post back when I tried to get the request parameters the signedRequest is NULL.

The same one is working on the intial load of the page first time but not on post back. I am testing the page in Canvas Preview.

```
 Map<String, String[]> parameters  = request.getParameterMap();
    String[] signedRequest = parameters.get("signed_request");
```

Thnaks.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas passes this liquid object as "signed_object" parameter when you load a page. I guess when you are submitting the AJAX post call, your application is submitting the form and it is clearing all the params for last URL.

This is a very common scenario and that's why salesforce supports to regenerate this parameter. Refer below URL to regenerate this using Canvas SDK.

```
  // Gets a signed request on demand.

  Sfdc.canvas.client.refreshSignedRequest(function(data) {
        if (data.status === 200) {
            var signedRequest =  data.payload.response;
            var part = signedRequest.split('.')[1];
            var obj = JSON.parse(Sfdc.canvas.decode(part));
        }
    }
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_app_refresh_signed_request.htm

Answer (score 0):

Thank You, it worked. I have one more thing to ask, I am doing POST and had the Apex class expose as rest service but I am getting 400 error. In debug logs I can see my do Post method was called and after that I could not see the debug line got executed.
var sr = JSON.parse('<%=signedRequestJson%>');
var url = sr.client.instanceUrl + "/services/apexrest/Account/";
 Sfdc.canvas.client.ajax(url,
                      {client : sr.client,
                       method: 'POST',
                       contentType: "application/json",
                        data: '{"name" : "Test Account" , "phone" : "1234567890"}', // Passing Accoutn name and phone
                       success : function(data) {
                           Sfdc.canvas.byId('arstatuspost').innerHTML = data.status;

@RestResource(urlMapping='/Account/*')
global with sharing class AccountRestService{

@HttpPost
    global static String doPost(String name,
        String phone) {
        system.debug('In Post');
        Account account = new Account();
        account.Name = name;
        account.phone = phone;
        insert account;
        return account.Id;
    }
}

```
                   }
```